# C# building/resource/publish/create and exe file with database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio

I was wondering how can I create the exe file for the app I made. I tried giving the exe file in the bind/debug folder together with the database (MS Access). But having an error with the filename of the mdb file, it is pointing to my directory.

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                                        Data Data Source=C:\Users\asdf\Documents\questionbank.mdb;
                                        Persist Security Info=True;
                                        Jet OLEDB:Database Password=asdfasdf";
}
```

And the error getting is "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permission to access the item.

Answer (score 0):

Put your connection string in a configuration file, eg., by createing a setting in the Settings tab when you right click on your project and go to Properties.

Hard coding your connection details, as you've done, means it cannot change when you deploy your application.

Comment: in my project properties. i have checked my settings tab. and change it to something like this

Type > connectiong string
Value > equal to "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
                                        Data Data Source=C:\Users\asdf\Documents\questionbank.mdb"

Comment: OK, and did you change the setting in the config file after you deployed?

Comment: Are you logging the path? If it's not a valid path then there's either an encoding issue or the path is otherwise genuinely not correct.

Comment: hmm. just accessing the database.